# iOS View Controller Life Cyle

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, lifecycle, viewcontroller

I'm facing some weird behavior in my map based App. I'm fetching some data to display a route using some directions service. It runs in an background thread using GCD. With the data fetched I return to the main thread to update the UI :

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.mapProvider addToExistingPolyLinePoints:coordinates withTitle:@"line" removeOldOne:NO useCurrentIndex:NO];

            [_distanceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2lf km",[self.draggingLogic getOverallDistance]]];
            [self.progress setHidden:YES];
        });
```

This all works fine in my RouteViewController. But if I go back to the RootViewController using the back button and reenter the RouteViewController and refetch the whole thing, the UI does not get evaluated. It shows the same behavior as if the UI update is not done in the main thread. The data arrives correct.

I'm wondering if it is some kind of issue regarding the view controller life-cycle of iOS, which I did not got completely. What happens when I push the back button. Obviously the ViewController is not destroyed but if I reenter it will create a new one. Is it possible from the RootViewController to determine if an instance of the target view controller is existing and perform the Segue using it?

Anyway, I'm not sure if this is regarding my issue.

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Haha. RouteViewController == "Root"ViewController? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right what you wrote, you create a new controller every time you "enter" but the dispatching block always refer to the first one you create, so the new one is displayed but the old one get the notifications...
There are lots of way to avoid this, depends on your implementation, but a simple solution may be keep a (strong) reference to the map view controller in a property of the root view controller: if it's nil (first time) you create the map controller and do all the needed stuffs, else you'll simply show it, without the creation part.

example code, in .h:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) MyMapController* mapController;
```

in .m:

```
if (!self.mapController)
{
    // create the controller and the update handler...
    self.mapController = ... //created object
}

// show it and everything...
```

hope this help

Comment: actually that made it :D I already had this reference to compare instances, but I was not using it when pushing the view controller. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
You are needed to do the stuff given here....   
you create a new controller every time you "enter" but the dispatching block always refer to the first one you create, so the new one is displayed but the old one get the notifications... 

Ex-code, in Interface file :

@property (strong,nonatomic) MyMapProvider* mapProvider;

And in implementation file :

if (!self.mapProvider)
{
    self.mapProvider = ... //create object
}

// do your stuff..
```